# Can't figure out why some controls are being clipped

Tags: wpf, layout, styles

So I have buttons that extend beyond the grid they are in, but they only show up on mouse over.  In some grids they render correctly and some they are rendered incorrectly.  It seems to be consistent which ones are incorrect, but I cannot figure out why the issue occurs on those particular grids. I looked at the elements with snoop and can't see any issues with the properties as they are being rendered.

Correct rendering:

[image]

Incorrect rendering:

[image]

Here's the code

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="GridItemScroller" Height="300">
    <ItemsControl Margin="0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rowItemsView}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Margin"  Value="{Binding RowIndex, Converter={StaticResource IndexToPositionConverter}, ConverterParameter=20}" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid x:Name="itemPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClipToBounds="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Filtered, Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}" Content="{Binding RowName}" />
                    <Canvas x:Name="CheckBoxButtonPanel" Grid.Column="1" ClipToBounds="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" Height="2">
                        <Canvas.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=itemPanel, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="10" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Canvas.Style>
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="15" Width="25" Canvas.Top="-15" local:ToolIcon.IconName ="{Binding Source={StaticResource LanguageInfo}, XPath=//Strings/@Up}" local:ToolIcon.Image="pack://application:,,,/CalUI;component/images/Up.png"  
                            Style="{DynamicResource ToolIcon}" Click="Move_Up"/>
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="15" Width="25" Canvas.Top="2" local:ToolIcon.IconName ="{Binding Source={StaticResource LanguageInfo}, XPath=//Strings/@Down}" local:ToolIcon.Image="pack://application:,,,/CalUI;component/images/Down.png"  
                            Style="{DynamicResource ToolIcon}" Click="Move_Down"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here's the XAML for the ToolIcon Style

```
<Style x:Key="ToolIcon" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="ImageGrid">
                    <Grid.Effect>
                        <local:SaturationLuminanceEffect SaturationShift="0.95" LuminanceShift="0.8" />
                    </Grid.Effect>
                    <Image x:Name="image" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="{TemplateBinding local:ToolIcon.Image}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="ImageGrid">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <local:SaturationLuminanceEffect SaturationShift="1" LuminanceShift="1.2" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="ImageGrid">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <local:SaturationLuminanceEffect SaturationShift="1.05" LuminanceShift="1.0" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="ImageGrid">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <local:SaturationLuminanceEffect SaturationShift="0.80" LuminanceShift="1.3" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Does it ListView control? If yes - you can use built in ListView.ScrollViewer instead of wrapping the ItemsControl by your own

Comment: I' using my own because these items are actually the visibility and order properties of a data grid, so each row here corresponds to a datagrid in another area of the app.

Comment: Sorry but still not clear for me, what you mean saying that you items "the visibility and order properties of a data grid"

Comment: Yes, uncheck a box here a row on a datagrid somewhere else disappears, re-order a row hear (using the buttons), a datagrid also has the order of it's rows change. The issue is just why the rendering of the buttons is sometimes wrong. Why are the buttons being clipped?

Comment: Clipping can be a tricky business. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810769/why-do-my-panels-clip-all-the-way-around-the-panel-when-made-smaller-than-the-exp) for more info on the subject.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the problem with that much code (custom attached properties etc.) Any chance you can make it smaller or perhaps upload a sample project which reproduces this problem?

Comment: @ CodeNaked, any chance you could upgrade your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the rendered items in Snoop?

http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[@CodeNaked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142794/codenaked) had the following insight in a comment:

> Clipping can be a tricky business. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810769/why-do-my-panels-clip-all-the-way-around-the-panel-when-made-smaller-than-the-exp) question for more info on the subject.

- The question mentioned is «[Why do my panels clip all the way around the panel when made smaller than the explicit size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810769/why-do-my-panels-clip-all-the-way-around-the-panel-when-made-smaller-than-the-exp)»