# Drawn rectangle not seen out of wpf grid

Tags: wpf, grid, drawing

I apology for my English grammar weakness. I try to draw a rectangle in a WPF grid. I draw it but this rectangle isn't seen in the right and bottom side of grid. What should i do? This is my XAML and code.

<
Window x:Class="DrawCircle.MainWindow"

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="window_MousLefteUp" MouseRightButtonUp="window_MouseRightButtonUp"
    MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
    MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" >

<Grid x:Name="window"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="PaleGreen"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="False">

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>

            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform1" ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform1" X="0" Y="0" />

        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

</Grid>
```

Its behind code is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    bool cornerPointed = false;
    Point corner1;
    Rectangle myRectangle;        

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRectangle.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        myRectangle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        myRectangle.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        window.Children.Add(myRectangle);
    }
    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        cornerPointed = true;
        corner1 = new Point(e.GetPosition(this.window).X, e.GetPosition(this.window).Y);
        myRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(corner1.X, corner1.Y, 0, 0);
    }

    private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cornerPointed == true)
        {
            Point corner2 = e.GetPosition(this.window);
            myRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(System.Math.Min(corner1.X, corner2.X),
                                               System.Math.Min(corner1.Y, corner2.Y),
                                               0, 0);
            myRectangle.Width = Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(this.window).X - corner1.X);
            myRectangle.Height = Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(this.window).Y - corner1.Y);
        }
    }

    private void window_MousLefteUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        cornerPointed = false;
        myRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRectangle.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        myRectangle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        myRectangle.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        window.Children.Add(myRectangle);

    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard top tell what you're asking from this post but on running your example I can see that red rectangles get drawn properly inside the grid until you hit the edge of the grid where the right and bottom sides don't get drawn, is this what you're trying to stop?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why the green grid does not fill the whole of the window? If so, it is because of this line, which scales the width and height of the grid down by 50%:

```
<ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform1" ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
```

If that is not the problem, please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: I put the ScaleTransform because I will use it later to zoom in and zoom out.

Comment: I will put some UIElements into the grid plus rectangle, shapes and text that will play annotation role in the grid. I put the ScaleTransform because I will use it later to zoom in and zoom out the window. So, my problem is to draw some annotations freely in the grid with zooming capability.

Comment: OK so that appears to be working ok at present. The grid is zoomed to half of the width and half of the height of the window. And you can draw the red rectangles inside it. Which part is not working correctly?

Comment: When I zoom in/out the green grid, I want to zoom in/out the rectangle too. The problem is when I zoom out, I can't place the rectangle every where I want.

Comment: The same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810769/why-do-my-panels-clip-all-the-way-around-the-panel-when-made-smaller-than-the-ex

Comment: I added this but the problem didn't solved.


    public class MyGrid : Grid
    {
        protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

Comment: @HosseinFattahian - sorry to keep asking, but I still don't understand *exactly* what you want. Are you saying that you want to be able to draw a red rectangle outside of the green grid when the greedn grid is zoomed out? Please explain the problem exactly.

Comment: 1-I have a green grid that it has some images in it. Suppose the green grid is an image.
2-I draw a rectangle as annotation around an image. This rectangle should be drawn in any zoom and every where of window.
3-Both of rectangle and images should be zoom in/out without changing relative distance.

My problem is I can't draw the rectangle at bottom and right side of grid. The grid is horizontally left and vertically top alignment. If I use another grid for annotation something like that Bill did, it doesn't solve the problem because when I zoom out, still I can't draw it out of second grid.

Answer (score 0):

The scaletransform is shrinking your green grid.  Since you're drawing the red rectangles on the green grid directly it makes it so that the red rectangles can't go beyond the green.

If you want to have the green be that small size but still have red go everywhere then you can just use another grid like this:

```
  <Grid x:Name="window">
    <Grid Background="PaleGreen">
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
          <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform1" ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
          <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform1" X="0" Y="0" />
        </TransformGroup>
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

EDIT:
Here's an additional example that uses a slider to demonstrate a "zoom" effect.  The red rectangles are also zoomed when you move the slider.

```
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Slider x:Name="sldZoom" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="1"/>
    <Grid Background="PaleGreen" x:Name="window">
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
          <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform1"
                          ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=sldZoom, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                          ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=sldZoom, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TransformGroup>
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
```

EDIT2:
if you want to, you can also change the scale of the slider (or whatever binding property you use).  For instance.. instead of using a 0-1 scale you could use a 0-10 scale.  This means, when you set it to 10 you have a 10x zoom effect.

If you want to disable zooming out to the point where you get whitespace that you can't write on then set the base scale at 1.  Here's a slider you can drop into my above sample that will give you a 1-10x scale. This will prohibit the user from zooming out to the point where they get unwritable area.  (you can play with the numbers to get whatever settings you're comfortable with).

```
<Slider x:Name="sldZoom" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" Value="2"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to zoom in/out the green grid. I want to zoom the rectangle too and I want to place the rectangle every where I want. When I zoom in, I don't have any problem; but when I zoom out I can't place the rectangle at the right and bottom of window.

Comment: No problem.  All you need to do is bind your scaleX and scaleY to a property.  Then, when you modify your property the green rec will scale(zoom) to match.  The red rectangles will also scale. Check my edited answer for a working example.

Comment: I found the answer. Please see http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/12/28/cliptoboundsmaybe/. Now I want to override GetLayoutClip. If I do this, I think I will solve the problem.

Comment: The same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810769/why-do-my-panels-clip-all-the-way-around-the-panel-when-made-smaller-than-the-ex

Comment: I agree with Stephen, You'll need to be more descriptive as to the functionality that you want.  Otherwise you're just setting us up for failure by having to make assumptions.  Please make an edit to your original question that exactly describes your desired functionality.

Comment: 1-I have a green grid that it has some images in it. Suppose the green grid is an image.
2-I draw a rectangle as annotation around an image. This rectangle should be drawn in any zoom and every where of window.
3-Both of rectangle and images should be zoom in/out without changing relative distance.

My problem is I can't draw the rectangle at bottom and right side of grid. The grid is horizontally left and vertically top alignment. If I use another grid for annotation something like that Bill did, it doesn't solve the problem because when I zoom out, still I can't draw it out of second grid.

Comment: You can do this using my approach.  You simply need to define bounds on your zoom.  ie: figure out how far out is reasonable for zooming and then lay out your grids to match this limit. You can choose whatever limits you want but you wont be able to make it unlimited without getting the 'unwritable' area in the bottom&right.  If you tell me the limits you desire then i can write up a quick example for you. (another option is to shrink the window as they zoom out so that you don't get unwritable area)

Comment: The zoom value will never be lower than 0.2. Would you help me to do this?