# WPF ToolBar and StackPanel turns ClipToBounds="True" automatically when cropped

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

I need to display in WPF some child items in toolbar outside its bounds (buttons on toolbar grows when hovered by cursor).

[Image 1: Right panel behavior: ClipToBounds="False"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjya1.png)

All is right when ClipToBounds="False" and all buttons have a place inside toolbar. The trouble occurs when part of the panel cropped by edge of the window and there is no place for some buttons. In this case ToolBar and StackPanel switch ClipToBounds property to "True" automatically and starts to crop children.

[Image 2: Wrong panel behavior: ClipToBounds snaps to "True"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOrKL.png)

Can I disable this behavior or there is no way except to draw buttons on wide topmost transparent container?

Comment: Not outside of the Window.  It sounds like you're saying the Window becomes the border and it switches ClipToBounds to True.  Just add a binding that will change it to false when it's not on the border of the Window maybe.  Could you post the XAML and describe when it swaps a bit more?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII shure! I've edited the post.

Comment: Just shrink the window to see panel contents clipping:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkTKw.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution (just split toolbar into layers):

```
<Window x:Class="ZoomBarMockup.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="200" Width="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="#CCC"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="#CCC"/>

        <!-- Decorative toolbar background strip -->
        <Border Grid.Row="1">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#DDD" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>            
        </Border>

        <!-- Wide transparent panel with negative margin -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" ClipToBounds="False"
                    Height="50" Margin="0 -10 0 -10">
            <Ellipse Fill="Orange" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="Orange" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="Orange" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="Orange" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="Orange" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5 0"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable panel's default clipping behavior. But in order to do it you have to extend one of the existing panels or implement your own:

```
class NoClipStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812112/1386995) to get more details about different clipping methods.

Comment: Oh, It's brilliant! Thank you!